# RSpec message expectations not being met but method is called

Tags: rspec, mocking

I have the following test:

```
  describe "Exporter#get_method" do
    before(:each) do
      exporter.should_receive(:get_method).at_least(:once).and_call_original
    end

    it "should get the next terminal value" do
      exporter.send(:get_method).should == :split
    end

    it "should call descend if the current value is a hash" do
      exporter.should_receive(:descend).once

      2.times { exporter.send(:get_method) }
    end

    it "should call ascend if at the end of an array and there is a prologue" do
      exporter.should_receive(:ascend).once

      3.times { exporter.send(:get_method) }
    end
  end
```

I can verify with a couple of binding.pry calls that ascend and descend are being called.  However RSpec isn't seeing it.  Where am I going wrong.  I want to make sure that the method being tested does call the other methods under the correct circumstances.  Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I tend to never put expectations in `before` blocks. The way I see it, `before` blocks are really just for setting up the situation you're testing, not to DRY out expectations. What happens when you move `exporter.should_receive(:get_method).at_least(:once).and_call_original` out of the `before` block and distribute it in the 3 `it` blocks (editing it as necessary in each of the three cases)? It's possible it's conflicting with the other `should_receive` calls.

Also, would it work if you called `exporter.get_method`, instead of `exporter.send(:get_method)`? Generally, RSpec is intended to test behavior, not implementation, and if `get_method` is a private method, there's not really any point in testing it directly. Instead, what you might want to do is write tests for the methods that use that private method. Otherwise, if it's not a private method, why are you using `:send`?

Comment: No dice.  I get the same failures with the call_original in the specific it blocks.  It's a private method.  However I would like passing tests so that I know if I break it in the future.  Either by changing the conditions under which it makes decisions or by modifying the method and not realizing that I have also modified the behavior.

Comment: Are there any other stubs in the file (perhaps way up at the top)? That's a trap that'll get you often...

Comment: Not really, just two let statements:  let (:exporter) { Export::Exporter.new 'data', [:split, { :to_s => [:split] }] }
  let (:formats) { { :xls => Export::Formatters::XLSFormatter, :csv => Export::Formatters::CSVFormatter } }

Comment: Make sure that the same instance of `Export::Exporter` that is sent the `should_receive` message in the spec is the same instance that receives `ascend` or `descend`. It's possible that it's a different instance of the same class.

Comment: Moving the should_receive out of the before and into the tests should have addressed that but they still failed.

Comment: Can you post your latest code, both for the spec and the class being tested?